# Display input step as popup so that its intuitive in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, input, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Input step in my Jenkins Pipeline. In Teamcity, input step is very intuitive where a popup is displayed to accept the input.

In Jenkins Pipeline, the build pauses with a link to "Input Requested" to accept the input.

Is there a way to display the input step as a popup in Jenkins Pipeline similar to Teamcity one?

Answer (score 9):

Yes, when you are using Pipelines and you are using the View Pipeline plugin, you should run your project and execute your input steps inside a STAGE, for example:

```
stage 'check-in'
node ('master') {
    input 'Are you sure?'
}
```

And will get something like:

[image]

Instead, if you are monitoring the console, you will be prompted as you described.

Comment: Agreed. But I was looking for something similar to teamcity one because this is still not intuitive to the user. I guess may be this is the best we can get in jenkins.

Comment: Look the Blue Ocean pluggin as suggested in another answer, either way Blue ocean is just too new for production

Comment: for a strange reason once i get my popup and i click proceed,  it just grayout but nothing happen, is like never sent the responds, i need to go inside the job, and click on the right 'Paused for Input' and that way does work,     any one know if the popup is bug?

Comment: @pelos hard to tell, Jenkins has been doing a lot of fixes and delivering a lot of bugs, I think it might depend what version are you using

Comment: i am using Jenkins 2.263.4 so not sure, i usually go inside the job, and click on the left panel paused for input, or just go to the bottom of the console log and click input and i do it from there.

Answer (score 2):

While it's not exactly the same, the UI rewrite plugin called Blue Ocean ( https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Blue+Ocean+Plugin ) is now past 1.0 and has a much better interface for the input step.

I used this Jenkinsfile:

```
node(){
    stage("primary"){
        echo 'test'
        input "This is a question?"
    }
}
```

And here's how it looks in Blue Ocean:

[Blue Ocean Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvOmt.png)

Comment: is the user input triggered with a hover? Or does it automatically popup?

Comment: yes - it is triggered with hover. Also, you don't have to place input inside the node() because this will lock the worker. You can define stage for input without node()

Comment: This doesn't works for Parameters that are not added by a plugin like [Extensible choice paramere plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Extensible+Choice+Parameter+plugin'). Which results in another click back to old jenkins UI

Answer (score 0):

> Agreed. But I was looking for something similar to teamcity one because this is still not intuitive to the user. I guess may be this is the best we can get in jenkins.

@tulika how is this achieved in teamcity?

```
input 'Deploy to Production?'
```

gives me

```
input: not found
Process exited with code 127
```